# Stuck on "Installing build dependencies ... \" while installing scikit-lean on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get stuck when i use pip install to install scikit-learn on jupyter notebook

[image]

I tried to find other solution that I found on internet but it is always the same issue

[image]

Comment: what's the error you receive? in those pictures it just says that it's started installing the package.

Answer (score 1):

I was opening jupyter notebook with sagemath, it seems that the problem was from it. It works if I open jupyter notebook without sagemath